# Accessing form elements filling fields?

Tags: vxml, voicexml

I have a form which has an initial element, I am running a check using the confidence feature to check for other phrases that might match the user's input. If there are then i am going to a menu, from here i am asking the user to input a dtmf value to say whether one of these values where correct. If the user selects an option, i want it to fill that field of which it checked, with that interpretation or possibly go to another form which does the same thing, if i choose to do it using the other form, can u access filled fields from another form?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [VoiceXML Specification the scope](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml5.1.2) for that type of variable would only be accessible in the form. But you can assign the values to another variable before leaving the form that has document scope (i.e. defined just below the vxml tag).  Or even give it global scope by defining the variable in the root document, which makes it accessible to the whole application.